# Laravel6.0 Eloquent can't get specific column name value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update our system from `Laravel4.2` to `Laravel6.0`.
Our Database is `AWS Aurora` with `PostgreSQL10.7`.

I use Eloquent to get to the table record.
When I run this:

```
$obj = self::find($id);
```

The Specific column "start" and "end" is always in NULL.
Our old system(`Laravel4.2`) didn't have this problem.

Where is the problem?
thank you

---

[Add 20-11-2019]
My table structure is here.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.sub_markets (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    market_id int4 NOT NULL,
    parent_id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1'::integer,
    team_id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1'::integer,
    "type" int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::smallint,
    area_size float8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::double precision,
    exist_family_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    initial_blank_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    blank_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    initial_unmatch_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    unmatch_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    initial_share_unmatch_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    share_unmatch_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    contract_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    reserve_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fulltalk_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    revisit_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    absence_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    rumor_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ifo_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fo_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ban_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    exempt_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    exempt2_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    co_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    is_area_lock int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::smallint,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
    "start" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
    "end" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
    polygon text NULL,
    classroom_body text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sub_markets_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and I defined this model class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Markets;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Log;

use App\Markets\SubMarketUser;

// SubMarket情報
class SubMarket extends MarketBase
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'sub_markets';
...
    public static function findById($id)
    {
        $obj = self::find($id);
        Log::debug(__METHOD__,['obj'=>$obj]);
        return $obj;
    }
...
}
```

I exec this function, getting this log.

> [2019-11-20 10:23:25] local.DEBUG: App\Markets\SubMarket::findById {"obj":{"App\Markets\SubMarket":{"id":246,"market_id":258,"parent_id":-1,"team_id":-1,"type":1,"area_size":"0.17","exist_family_count":155,"initial_blank_count":0,"blank_count":0,"initial_unmatch_count":0,"unmatch_count":4,"initial_share_unmatch_count":0,"share_unmatch_count":0,"contract_count":92,"reserve_count":1,"fulltalk_count":2,"revisit_count":1,"absence_count":1,"rumor_count":2,"ifo_count":1,"fo_count":0,"ban_count":0,"exempt_count":0,"exempt2_count":1,"co_count":3,"is_area_lock":0,"created_at":"2019-11-18 14:22:51","updated_at":"2019-11-19 11:14:43","deleted_at":null,"start":null,"end":null,"polygon":"MULTIPOLYGON([HERE IN POLYGON POINT VALUE])","classroom_body":"{[HERE IN JSON INFOMATION]}"}}}

Log output `"start":null,"end":null,`.
But this record has `start` and `end` value.

```sql
select id,market_id,"start", "end" from sub_markets where id=246;

id |market_id|start              |end                |
---|---------|-------------------|-------------------|
246|      258|2019-11-18 14:22:51|2019-11-18 14:22:51|
```

Why is it?

---

[Add2019-11-21]

I am trying other test.

```php
public static function findById($id)
{
    $obj = self::find($id);
    Log::debug(__METHOD__,['obj1'=>$obj->start]);
    $tmp = DB::table('sub_markets')->select('id','start','end')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
    Log::debug(__METHOD__,['tmp1'=>$tmp]);
    $obj->start = Common::utc2Datetime('2019-11-18 11:11:11');
    $obj->end = Common::utc2Datetime('2019-11-18 15:55:55');
    Log::debug(__METHOD__,['obj2'=>$obj->start]);
    $obj->save();
    Log::debug(__METHOD__,['obj3'=>$obj->start]);
    $tmp = DB::table('sub_markets')->select('id','start','end')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
    Log::debug(__METHOD__,['tmp2'=>$tmp]);
    return $obj;
}
```

Executing this code. Output log is here.

> [2019-11-20 15:14:29] local.DEBUG: App\Markets\SubMarket::findById {"obj1":null}
>   [2019-11-20 15:14:29] local.DEBUG: App\Markets\SubMarket::findById {"tmp1":{"stdClass":{"id":246,"start":"2019-11-19 10:00:00","end":"2019-11-19 15:00:00"}}}
>   [2019-11-20 15:14:29] local.DEBUG: App\Markets\SubMarket::findById {"obj2":null}
>   [2019-11-20 15:14:29] local.DEBUG: App\Markets\SubMarket::findById {"obj3":null}
>   [2019-11-20 15:14:29] local.DEBUG: App\Markets\SubMarket::findById {"tmp2":{"stdClass":{"id":246,"start":"2019-11-18 11:11:11","end":"2019-11-18 15:55:55"}}}
>   $obj->start is always null. But database is updating new time.

Is it Laravel6.0's bug?

---

My problem is cleared.

I rechecked our program. In MarketBase.php this function. I deleting it, start/end value can getting.

```php
class MarketBase extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = array('id');

/*
    public function getStartAttribute()
    {
        return Common::datetime2Utc($this['attributes']['start']);
    }
    public function getEndAttribute()
    {
        return Common::datetime2Utc($this['attributes']['end']);
    }
*/
```

I don't know that cause, but it was solved for this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What's your model definition and what's your table structure and how are you using the shared code?

Comment: Does the `MarketBase` class have `$casts` set? Have you tried adding start/end to the `$dates` array so it's turned into a proper Carbon object? Have you tried renaming the fields to a non-reserved name as a test?